# TabBarIOS UI customization

Tags: ios, user-interface, reactjs, react-native

So I am looking to customize the TabBarIOS ui a little bit.  Right now the TabBar has an icon field and a name field: 
 iconName="ios-pin"
 title="Map"

Using these results in something like this (with the icon above the text):

[image]

However I am trying to get something that looks a like this (with the icon next to the text p.s sorry for the crappy image)

[image]

Does anyone have any idea how to do this? Below is my current TabBarIOS code.

Thanks!

```
renderScene(route, navigator) {
    return (
      <TabBarIOS
        translucent={false}
        unselectedTintColor="white"
        tintColor="#f9c827"
        barTintColor="#2c2c2c">

        <Icon2.TabBarItemIOS
          iconName="ios-pin"
          title="Map"
          selectedIconName="ios-pin"
          selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'MapTab'}
          onPress={() => {
            this.setState({
              selectedTab: 'MapTab',
            });
          }}>
          {this.renderMap(route, navigator)}
        </Icon2.TabBarItemIOS>

        <Icon2.TabBarItemIOS
          iconName="ios-list-box-outline"
          title="List"
          selectedIconName="ios-list-box-outline"
          selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'ScrollTab'}
          onPress={() => {
            this.setState({
              selectedTab: 'ScrollTab',
              toolbar: YELLOW,
              navigationBar: NavigationBarYellow,
            });
          }}>
          {this.renderScrollView(route, 'ScrollTab')}
        </Icon2.TabBarItemIOS>


      </TabBarIOS>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to use images with text, the other one is to create container viewcontroller and use UIView instead of UITabbar. 
That view should have two buttons with icons and texts that you need.

Comment: I figured the easiest way to do it would be to use images with text are you aware of any free react-native icon sets like that?  I am currently using - react-native-vector-icons